# any idea why the visual studio code project directory ui displays differently for this scenario?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm working on a React project in Visual Studio Code.  For some reason, the subdirectory structure that I just added displays subdirs via slashes () instead of rendering the subdirs in a treeview:

[image]

Any idea why VS Code would do this?  Other subdir structures in the project display as normal treeviews as expected

Comment: Add a screenshot please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably because those folders are empty and contain empty folders also
Try adding files to them it won't display that way anymore

NB: There's no big deal with that display

Now if you want it to display normally:

Select Preferences,then Settings. Then Search for "compact folders" and uncheck the checkbox